# Working with SonarQube rules

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube and using SonarQube 5.1. I read from somewhere that it is a replacement for FindBugs and CheckStyle. So does it mean it internally runs FindBugs and CheckStyle? But I counldn't find any FindBugs and CheckStyle plugins inbuilt. From where does Sonar take the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Checkstyle and FindBugs plugins separately, enable their rules in your profile and thus use them in your analysis. However, @SonarSource has made a concerted effort to replace such rules with 'native' rules, and if you do install these extra plugins, you will find many of their rules marked Deprecated.

You can see the replacement progress in the deprecation reports for [FindBugs](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/findbugs.html), [Checkstyle](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/checkstyle.html) and [PMD](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/pmd.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can install FindBugs and CheckStyle from the Update Center, on the administration section of SonarQube (default: login as user "admin" with password "admin" )

Once installed the plugins, when you do a sonar analysis in your code (for example: mvn sonar:sonar ), the machine running the analysis will get the .jars from Sonar itself, run locally, and then upload the results back to Sonar.